# Remote Connection to MongoDB Running on Linux Server

Tags: linux, mongodb, networking

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB instance running on a remote Linux server.  The connection attempt is timing out leading me to suspect network settings on the Linux server as I can ssh to the server and connect to MongoDB locally.

`/etc/mongod.conf` does not have the `bind_ip` set, so that is not the issue.

Can anyone point me to how I can troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you telnet to the MongoDB port from the remote host and connect successfully?

If so, that means the port is open, the connection works and it's not a firewall/iptables etc. issue.  You should look into the next piece - do you have authentication enabled?

If you can't connect with telnet, then something is blocking you from getting from the remote host to that port.  It could be firewall, or it could be on the host - it really depends on your set up and infrastructure.

Comment: `telnet` is timing out, so I suppose it is a firewall/iptables issue.  Do you know where I would find the configurations for these?

Comment: That will really depend on where you have this deployed.  First, make sure (again) that the localhost connection succeeds.  Next, for the local stuff on Linux, first make sure you are not running SELinux or similar (really just a RHEL thing).  Next you'll want to check iptables to see if you are dropping anything (as root: `iptables -L -vn`).  For non-local firewall settings you are going to need to contact your network admin, or check out security zones for Amazon, or whatever your equivalent is.

Answer (score 1):

Remove any lock acquired by the mongoDB
    sudo rm -rf /data/configdb/mongod.lock;

Create the data directories for the config and shard servers

```
sudo mkdir /data;
sudo mkdir /data/db;
sudo mkdir /data/configdb;
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /data;
sudo chmod -R 755 /data
```

Give the rights to the above created folders.
Give ownership to the above created folders.

Now try to connect to mongodb, It will surely connect now.